# Io () function frontend - socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I don't understand how it is possible that when i call `io ()` function into index.html for example, nodejs know that must perform `io.on ()` function. I understand that `io ()` function into index.html is used for open a new connection between client and server... but i don't understand the communication between client and server with socket.io.
Maybe because into server, i require socket.io and then socket.io into the server listen eventually request for execute `on ()` function.

But for do this, socket. Io must obtained the entire http + express package for listen the requests from the client ...is right?

Thanks all 
Morris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear exactly what you're asking, but in the client:

```
var socket = io();
```

is a shortcut for:

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

That attempts to establish a socket.io connection to the same host and port that the current web page was loaded from and store an object representing that connection in the `socket` variable.

> but i don't understand the communication between client and server
>   with socket.io.

If the server is listening for a socket.io connection, then `io()` will connect to that server.  From then on, the client can either listen for incoming messages with `socket.on('someMsg', fn)` or the client can send messages to the server with `socket.emit('someMsg, someData);`.

Likewise, the server can either listen for incoming messages from the client or emit new messages to the client.

> But for do this, socket. Io must obtained the entire http + express
>   package for listen the requests from the client ...is right?

Well, sort of.  If you want a single web server that serves both your web pages and can accept socket.io connections, then you will need at least the http module (for the server) and the socket.io module (for the socket.io server).  If you want a more full featured web server where you can define routes and many other features, then yes you would use Express and socket.io together.